# Excel - Iteration based on changing cell value, pasting result

Tags: excel, iteration

So I have set up a linear model in excel of passenger numbers and population. There are two decay parameters which change the forecasts of passenger numbers - for the different types of transport.

Manually I can change the decay factors 0.1-1.0 for every combination, to see how the fit of the model changes. I would like to find the combination of parameters that creates the best model fit at a 0.01 accuracy. Any ideas how?

Essentially the passenger forecasts change when setting parameters which in turn changes the model fit. I need an easy way to see how model fit changes with changing the parameters! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Solver doesn't seem to work for my problem but hadn't heard of What-if-Analysis - looks like it may be what I need